# MooTools Disable html elements with reference

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am using MooTools and I want to disable specific checkbox element, I tried with this code:

```
$$('#lbl-box-posts8 #Others').set().disabled = true;
```

But not working :(

**My HTML Code:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="property_type8">
        <div class="email_alert_checkbx_list_type">
            <label id="lbl-box-posts8" class="label_check c_on" for="Others">
                <input type="checkbox" value="Others" class="validate['group[1,1]'] chkBX" id="Others" name="type">Others
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**My Mootools Code:**

```
JHTML::_('behavior.mootools'); /* to load mootools */
$ajax = "
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
            $$('#lbl-box-posts8 #Others').set().disabled = true;    
        });
    })
    /* ]]> */
    ";
$doc =&JFactory::getDocument();
$doc ->addScriptDeclaration($ajax);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$$('#lbl-box-posts8 #Others').set('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: Exactly what I want :) but why this is not working `$$('#lbl-box-posts8 #Others').set().disabled = true;`. Can you explain me? Thanks

Comment: because that's not how the `set()` method works n_n http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:set

Comment: ids are unique. `document.id('Others').set('disabled', true)` is fine - or `$('Others')`. `.set()` chains and returns the element back anyway so setting `.disabled` may still work but not on a collection of elements, which is what `$$` returns. it will set a prop on the array instead.